# Google Analytics event not firing

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events

My Google Analytics event isn't firing on my webpage. Below is my code. It opens the url in a new tab just fine, and there are no errors in the console. But when I go to Google Analytics -> Real-Time -> Events my goal has no activity. It's using Universal Analytics because when I view page source I see analytics.js.

```
<a href="https://myurl.com" onclick="ga('send', 'MyEvent', 'Click');" target="_blank">under construction </a></p>
```

If it helps, my Goal setup is:

```
Category - MyEvent
Action - Click

Use the Event value as the Goal Value for the conversion - Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the hit type property.

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);
```

Full documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Comment: Dude you saved my life! Thanks! It works now. I'll make this the correct answer once the timer expires.

Comment: :D Glad I could help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using it like `<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'buttons', 'click', 'paypal');" ...`. But it's not working. [match-it](https://funcards.github.io/match-it/)

Comment: try prepending `javascript:`,`<a onclick="javascript:ga('send', 'event', 'buttons', 'click', 'paypal');`"

Comment: I debug and replaced ga function with `gtag` and now it is working.

Answer (score 3):

New version of analytics has a different syntax: Replace this line

```
ga('send', 'MyEvent', 'Click');
```

With

```
gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category' : 'MyEvent', 'event_action' : 'Click', 'event_label' : 'Label is optional'});"
```